# Google Sheets VLOOKUP using arrayformula not working

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I am trying to populate rows of data from another sheet using `VLOOKUP` and `ARRAYFORMULA`.

Here is the data where I am using `arrayformula`:

[image: Cells with arrayformula]

G2 has the formula:

```
=arrayformula(if(ISBLANK(E2:E),"",VLOOKUP(E2:E,'Product List'!$A$2:$C,2)*F2:F))
```

And here is the "Product List" from the other sheet:

[image: Product List]

As you can see, it is bringing in the wrong numbers:

[image]

What is wrong with my `arrayformula` that is making it do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the content in column E is not an exact match to something in column A, it will pull the closest match. If you don't want this, you can fix this by adding `FALSE` as the fourth parameter in `VLOOKUP`. By adding `FALSE` as shown below, cells that are not a match will show as `#N/A` instead of an incorrect number.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(E2:E),"",VLOOKUP(E2:E,'Product List'!$A$2:$C,2,FALSE)*F2:F))
```

Other than that, I don't see why the formula wouldn't work.

Comment: That's it! I would have tried that but I mistakingly assumed that `FALSE` was the default setting. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

just a slight modification of [the above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56954691/5632629) to account for possible errors and render out the unnecessary syntax elements in order to make it shorter

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E2:E="", , IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E2:E,'Product List'!A2:C, 2, 0))*F2:F))
```